discord.py how make update command
How to make a command in discord.py that will update all slash commands and add new slash commands, but without using cogs, I found a way only if I change the value of one of the current slash commands and write it twice, but this is too confusing

There's an example for slash commands in discord.py in here, Slash commands can be synced with tree.sync method and it'll sync every command that are registered with tree.command
